# Xamarin form: IValueConverter receive null value in Convert method

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, converters

I have a list view set with item source as child. I want to bind a child object to a view which will set the color through the converter.

The converter method got called but the value i passed in was `null`.

Apart from dot, I also use `Path=/` but the value passed to the converter still `null`. If i bind the property, it's fine but not the current item.

```
<ListView x:Name="childListView" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HasUnevenRows="true" 
    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
    ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout 
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}" 
                        Spacing="0" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <controls:CircleImage>
```

Comment: What does "." means in your code in the Binding of the `BackgroundColor`  property? If you show the code behind of this XAML it might be easier to find out

Comment: In XAML, value converters are usually instantiated in a `ResourceDictionary` and then referenced in a Binding expression by using the `StaticResource` markup extension. plz provide related code in order to get help.

Comment: The "." I used was being used in my other code which I have a group binding in the list, in the that group, I have either string, and other group of objects. The "." represent the current item in the list. I used that in the template selector instead of using it on IValueConverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phatye is definitely correct in saying the line

`BackgroundColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}"`

is the culprit. I too have attempted to use the `{Binding .}` and `{Binding Path=.}` with a converter in the past only to run into the same null reference issues you're running into. It seems that Xamarin doesn't like this.

The proper solution will be to pass the proper path of the property you want to bind to:

Assuming the property is a top level property

`BackgroundColor="{Binding Path=accounted, Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}"`

Otherwise you could do this:

`BackgroundColor="{Binding Path=topLevelProperty.accounted, Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}"`

Comment: I had a similar issue where my converter breakpoint would always trigger with `value` null when trying to pass the item in a data template using `Path=.`. @Ghasan's post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798095/132599 is correct - the converter will be called multiple times, initially with null and then with the object.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting bit of behavior. I recently had this while working with `CarouselView (Forms.Plugin)`, and doing more research, it turned out that the `BindingContext` of each of `CarouselView` element is set more than once for some reason.

So the first time, the converter gets `null` value, but eventually, it gets called a second time with the correct value, so I changed my converter to gracefully handle `null` values, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}"
```

That line is the likely culprit. It will only be valid if the binding context of the page is that single "AccountedTo" property. Change it to `"{Binding BackgroundProperty}"`
where "BackgroundProperty" is the "AccountedTo" value.