# Getting NullReferenceException in a ValueConverter

Tags: xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I have the following IValueConverter, StringCaseConverter.cs:

```cs
internal sealed class StringCaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool IsUpperCase { private get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        var stringValue = value.ToString();

        return this.IsUpperCase ? stringValue.ToUpperInvariant() : stringValue.ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I registered it in App.xaml:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:StringCaseConverter x:Key="StringToLowerCaseConverter" IsUpperCase="False"/>
        <converters:StringCaseConverter x:Key="StringToUpperCaseConverter" IsUpperCase="True"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And used it in MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>A</x:String>
                    <x:String>B</x:String>
                    <x:String>C</x:String>
                    <x:String>D</x:String>
                    <x:String>E</x:String>
                    <x:String>F</x:String>
                    <x:String>G</x:String>
                    <x:String>H</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="20"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource StringToLowerCaseConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When I run the application, I get a NullReferenceExecption in StringCaseConverter.cs (`var stringValue = value.ToString();`) because `value` parameter of `Convert()` method is null.

What am I missing?

Comment: test for value for null before referencing it

Comment: Is not this the string that is coming from the hard-coded list? how can it be null?

Comment: I don't know why but I believe it is a good practice to always test `object?.method()`

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. The converter is called 24 times in my example although the items on the list are 8 and there is only one label that is bound to the list items. Any explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44103919 it seems the converter is being called when created and before strings are instantiated.

Comment: This is strange. In my case, the converted was called 3 times per item; I get null, the item, then null, then null again, another item, then null, and so on. I'm going to report it as a bug.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123823/121097) was accepted as an answer in the question you linked to. When I'm binding to an item on a list, what other option do I have other than `{Binding}` or `{Binding .}`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a null value judgment.

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var stringValue = value.ToString();

        return this.IsUpperCase ? stringValue.ToUpperInvariant() : stringValue.ToLowerInvariant();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, this was not what I am asking about. Yes, I can check for null, but I am wondering why I am getting NullReferenceExecption when my data source does not contain null. Also, see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971368/getting-nullreferenceexception-in-a-valueconverter/63986088#comment113121629_63971368) and my bug report [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12183).

Answer (score 0):

CurrentException:

```
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueConverterProvider.Convert (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Xaml\ValueConverterProvider.cs:17 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingCondition.EqualsToValue (System.Object other) [0x00025] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Interactivity\BindingCondition.cs:79 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingCondition.OnBoundPropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Interactivity\BindingCondition.cs:89 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:512 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:446 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x00226] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:160 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x0003e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.<PropertyChanged>b__50_0 () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:773 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.PropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) [0x000cb] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:784 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+WeakPropertyChangedProxy.OnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00012] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:675 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
```

Solution:
I had two DataTrigger with Setter for one control. I removed the second DataTrigger. And done.